# how to extract few before words after finding a keyword in text using python

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I have a keyword "grand master" and I am searching for the keyword in the huge text. I need to extract 5 before words and 5 after words of the keyword (based on the position it might go to the next/before sentence also), and this keyword appears multiple times in huge text.

As a trail , first i tried to find the position of the keyword in the text, using`text.find()`, and found the keywords at 4 different positions

```
>>positions
>>[125, 567,34445, 98885445]
```

So tried to split the text based on spaces and taking first 5 words,

```
text[positions[i]:].split([len(keyword.split()):len(keyword.split())+5]
```

But how to extract the 5 words before that keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use

```
text[:position[i]].split()[-5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for this. For the first keyword match:

```
pattern = "(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) grand master (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)"
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    firstword_before = match.group(1) # first pair of parentheses
    lastword_before = match.group(5)

    firstword_after = match.group(6)
    lastword_after = match.group(10)
```

Parentheses in the pattern indicates the group number. First pair of parentheses corresponds to match.group(1), second pair of parentheses corresponds to match.group(2) and so on. If you want all the groups you can use:

```
match.groups() # returns tuple of groups
```

or

```
match.group(0) # returns string of groups
```

For all the keyword match in the text, use re.findall. Read [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
 for details.

P.S: There are better ways to write patterns. Thats just me being lazy.